# How to send a message to all servers

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I am a new Discord.js developer and I was wondering how to send a message to all guilds/servers that my bot is in.

There have been some answers before but they are all for old versions, can someone please help? I've tried this piece of neat code but it isn't working in the current version.

```js
Bot.on('message', async (message) => {
    if (message.content === "e") {
        var guildList = Bot.guilds.array();
        try {
            guildList.forEach(guild => guild.defaultChannel.send("message"));
        } catch (err) {
            console.log("Could not send message to " + guild.name);
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have replaced `.defaultChannel` with the following, which attempts to get a channel called *general*. If it can't, it tries to get the first channel. If that fails as well, it logs an error:

```js
const channel = guild.channels.cache.find(channel => channel.name === 'general') || guild.channels.cache.first();
if (channel) {
    ...
} else {
    console.log('The server ' + guild.name + ' has no channels.');
}
```

I have also changed to the [`Discord.Collection()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/collection/master/class/Collection) [`.each()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/collection/master/class/Collection?scrollTo=each) method instead of converting the collection into an array and using `.forEach()`.

```js
Bot.on('message', async (message) => {
    if (message.content === "e") {
        Bot.guilds.each(guild => {
            try {
                const channel = guild.channels.cache.find(channel => channel.name === 'general') || guild.channels.cache.first();
                if (channel) {
                    channel.send('message');
                } else {
                    console.log('The server ' + guild.name + ' has no channels.');
                }
            } catch (err) {
                console.log('Could not send message to ' + guild.name + '.');
            }
        });
    }
});
```